# Sudden delay in Raspberry while writing data to file

Tags: pi-3, timekeeping

I am using a raspberry Pi 3b+ (Linux raspberrypi 4.19.88-v7+ #1284 SMP Wed Dec 11 13:46:41 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux) to log data obtained from an experimental setup. I read data at 1kHz and dump it into a csv file using printf in c++. I log the time with a timer I wrote and get results

```
maxDelta: 0.00100067
maxDelta: 0.00100077
maxDelta: 0.00100083
maxDelta: 0.00100702
maxDelta: 0.00100718
maxDelta: 0.00103135
maxDelta: 0.0196419
```

where maxDelta is the maximum time in ms between two cycles.
As you can see everything is fine for ~30 seconds and then all of a sudden I use 19 ms instead of 1ms.
In every cycle I write 50 double values to the file, all in one printf command.
The timer compares two timestamps and then wastes time until the difference is bigger than 1ms.
When I look at the overhead I have in the timer routine I usually have 550us spare time in each cycle so the cycle time is not too short.
Can anyone point me in a direction of what to look for to solve the lagging issue?

*edit: I split the data aquisition and the logging up into two threads and increased both priority and niceness of the processes. This reduced the delay to 2 ms which is much better but still "bad" since I don't know where its from.
Any other ideas how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to wrap this up I tried a few things that improved performance a lot.

- As suggested by Milliways, using some form of non-blocking sleeping function reduced the CPU usage a lot.
- After using fprintf(...) I use fflush(...). That also reduced the times when an OS call would somehow intervene.
- Running the logger in its own thread helped separating hickups in the logger from the rest

overall I am now looking at deltaTimes in the 100 ns range and there are no more hickups bigger than 2 ms (worst case)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is a multi-user, multi-tasking operating system.  Something else might have needed the SD card (logging?) or CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to a file in Linux typically doesn't result in a write to the device. Written data end up in cache (RAM) and are *eventually* propagated to the SD card.

If you need more deterministic timing, write your own caching function. If your logging thread only ever writes to RAM (and a separate low-priority thread transfers that to the SD card), you will have much less lagging. You won't avoid lags completely though, since all threads are scheduled by the kernel, and if the kernel is busy doing something exclusive, the scheduling stops.

Answer (score 1):

There are a combination of factors involved, but without seeing your code it is difficult to be specific.

1. c buffers output internally until its internal buffer is full.
2. The OS caches disk I/O and will only perform actual I/O in blocks on
   an as needed basis.
3. The OS is multi-tasking and allocates time slices to many tasks so
   the actual execution time is unpredictable.

Your question implies you are using an idle loop to delay code execution. This is inefficient, and certainly not an efficient use of resources.

Comment: I realized the issue with the idle loop and added a nanosleep inside the loop to free up resources while the loop is waiting. That reduces the CPU usage drastically and it reduced the deltaTime peaks to around 2ms instead of one